# Remove Specific Characters/Strings/Sequences of Characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, tuples

I am creating a long list of what seem to be tuples that I would like to later convert into a Dataframe, but there are certain common sequences of characters that prevent this from being possible. And example of a fraction of the output:

```
0,"GAME_ID                      21900001
EVENTNUM                            2
EVENTMSGTYPE                       12
EVENTMSGACTIONTYPE                  0
PERIOD                              1
WCTIMESTRING                  8:04 PM
PCTIMESTRING                    12:00
HOMEDESCRIPTION                      
NEUTRALDESCRIPTION                   
VISITORDESCRIPTION                   
SCORE                             NaN
SCOREMARGIN                       NaN
PERSON1TYPE                         0
PLAYER1_ID                          0
PLAYER1_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
PERSON2TYPE                         0
PLAYER2_ID                          0
PLAYER2_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
PERSON3TYPE                         0
PLAYER3_ID                          0
PLAYER3_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
VIDEO_AVAILABLE_FLAG                0
DESCRIPTION                          
TIME_ELAPSED                        0
TIME_ELAPSED_PERIOD                 0
Name: 0, dtype: object"
```

Whereas the desired output would be:

```
GAME_ID                      21900001
EVENTNUM                            2
EVENTMSGTYPE                       12
EVENTMSGACTIONTYPE                  0
PERIOD                              1
WCTIMESTRING                  8:04 PM
PCTIMESTRING                    12:00
HOMEDESCRIPTION                      
NEUTRALDESCRIPTION                   
VISITORDESCRIPTION                   
SCORE                             NaN
SCOREMARGIN                       NaN
PERSON1TYPE                         0
PLAYER1_ID                          0
PLAYER1_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER1_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
PERSON2TYPE                         0
PLAYER2_ID                          0
PLAYER2_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER2_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
PERSON3TYPE                         0
PLAYER3_ID                          0
PLAYER3_NAME                      NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_ID                   NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_CITY                 NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_NICKNAME             NaN
PLAYER3_TEAM_ABBREVIATION         NaN
VIDEO_AVAILABLE_FLAG                0
DESCRIPTION                          
TIME_ELAPSED                        0
TIME_ELAPSED_PERIOD                 0
```

How can I get rid of the 0 and " at the start, and then the trash at the end past the `TIME_ELAPSED_PERIOD`? The int at the start and the one in the bottom row increases by 1 until the end of my program, which could likely go upwards of around 320,000, so I will need the code to be able to adapt for a range of int values. I think it would be easiest to do this after the creation of my list, so it shouldn't be necessary for me to show you any of my code. Just a systematic manipulation of characters should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more on this: "The int at the start and the one in the bottom row increases by 1 until the end of my program, which could likely go upwards of around 320,000". As per your explanation, it is not clear what is the type of your input data. Is it a list containing several batches of input data appended one after the other in the format you've explained or do you have separate lists for every batch of input data?

Comment: A similar block of data is repeated with the same row titles (i.e. PLAYER_3_ID), but the data for each row is different (this is a play-by-play worker for basketball games). The '0,"' that this data starts with, and the 'Name: 0, dtype: object"' that it ends with are parts I would like to remove. The next "block" of data below this would begin with '1," and end with 'Name: 1, dtype: object"', and each block after would have that number that shows up at the start and end increase by one. I would like to remove the 'x,"' and 'Name: x, dtype: object"' entirely, regardless of the value of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your input data is in the form of a list, you can try the following to meet your requirements:

```
inputlist = Your_list_to_be_corrected  #Assign your input list here

# Now, remove the rows in the list that have the format "Name: 0, dtype: object""
inputlist = [ x for x in inputlist if "dtype: object" not in x ]

#Now, correct the rows containing GAME_ID by removing the int number and special characters
sep = 'GAME_ID'
for index, element in enumerate(inputlist):
    if "GAME_ID" in element:
        inputlist[index] = 'GAME_ID' + element.split(sep, 1)[1]
```

Comment: Got this working with not in str(x), it turns out x is a tuple in this case. However, possession now returns as an empty list. The way possessions is structured is that possession[0] is equal to the entirety of the text block that I posted above, not just the first row. Is there any way to just search for and remove these unwanted characters?

Comment: As per my understanding, you have a list named "possessions" which contains tuples in it. For example, the entirety of the text block you provided is the contents of the first tuple in the list named "possessions". Can you also provide clarity as to whether the first tuple contains the entirety of the block of text you provided as a single string value? Meaning, does every tuple contain only one string value which has the entirety of the block of text you provided?

Comment: The tuple has 2 items in it. The first is an int (the 0 that appears at the beginning of the example). The second is a Series (from pandas), but when I grab a select value from the tuple, I'm only getting the values that appear to be in the second 'column' of the data shown. I am struggling to grab the actual column names (the first column of data) and the Name: 0, dtype: object seems to be one of these because I can't find it in the Series. I'll have to look somewhere for some pandas help, unless you have some yourself. I've tried converting it to a Df, but the columns don't work as intended.

Comment: I was able to remove it and convert to a Dataframe using your advice. Thanks!